# Android SQLite opens image URI, but unable to open content:

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I saved my image URI to splite and when I open my app, 
my app opens SQLite and gets the image URI.

But, when I get my image URI from my splite, this content Error occurs:

> Unable to open content:
>   content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A6230
>
> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from
>   ProcessRecord{86b9c15 17060:com.example.text/u0a254} (pid=17060,
>   uid=10254)  requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or
>   android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

**My app code:**

```
String allset=dbHelper.loadresult();// load db and get data
String[] data = allset.split(":"); // parse
String loadImgPath=data[2]; // load uri string
image1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(loadImgPath2));



image1.setImageURI << this is error
```

Comment: Instead of uri, try to use `byte[]` and store that in `blob` type in SQLite. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />` on the above of `<application>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file

and then check if your target and compile sdk is higher than lolipop then refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) link

Comment: i setted user-persmisson manage_documents , sdk version is very highest . i dont code this example ...